# Android programming sqlite database sorting query by String value to listview

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have a query that gets data from an sqlite database based on the Day value using a where clause, The data i'm getting is for 'Monday' this data is then populated into a listview. In addition to this i want to order the data by the time in ascending order to form a list with all events on monday from the earliest to latest Start times.

Query by day:

```
public Cursor getMonday () {
String Monday = "Monday";
return db.query(
    DATABASE_TABLE,
    new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_LESSON, KEY_DAY, KEY_START, KEY_END, KEY_LOCATION}, 
    KEY_DAY + "=?", 
    new String[] {Monday},
    null, null, null);
}
```

I've tried:

```
public Cursor getMonday () {
    String Monday = "Monday";
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
        new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_LESSON, KEY_DAY, KEY_START,KEY_END, KEY_LOCATION},
        KEY_DAY + "=?", 
        new String[] {Monday}, 
        null, null, null, 
        KEY_START + " ASC");
  }
```

This would usually work but i imagine that the WHERE clause and order by are not in the right order and i dont know how to make them work in unison. Could someone please advise? Thanks.

This is the error im getting:

```
01-28 14:24:02.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 14:24:02.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.unischeduler/com.example.unischeduler.ScheduleActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid LIMIT clauses:Start ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument order is incorrect, try this:

```
 public Cursor getMonday () {

 String Monday = "Monday";

 return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
         new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_LESSON, KEY_DAY, KEY_START,
                        KEY_END, KEY_LOCATION}, KEY_DAY + "=?", 
    new String[] {Monday}, null, null, KEY_START + " ASC", null);

  }
```

**EDIT** Proposal to order by hh:mm format:

Take a look to [SQLite Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and maybe you could try (I haven't tested it) something like this:

```
 return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
         new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_LESSON, KEY_DAY, KEY_START,
                        KEY_END, KEY_LOCATION}, KEY_DAY + "=?", 
    new String[] {Monday}, null, null, "strftime('%H:%M', " + KEY_START + ")", null);
```

Comment: If you use Eclipse, just put your mouse pointer over `query` and you will see the order and name of every argument of the method ^^

Comment: Thanks this solved my errors and my program compiles although just entering some test values the order of the list items seems to be incorrect, for example its showing the records in order of values 10, 13, 17 then 8. If i try it in DESC order i get from the top 8, 17, 13 then 10 and i'm not sure why?

Comment: You're welcome... then you can mark my answer as the correct one, can't you? About the ordering problem, bear in mind that SQLite doesn't support dates natively as MySQL does, in SQLite you are actually storing Strings, not Date instances. So the question is: what is the format of the dates you are storing?

Comment: I see, I'm storing them in hh:mm format as a 24 hour clock. So the test values currently look like this:
8:00, 13:00, 17:00, 10:00 etc
What would you recommend to correct this?